# Find in log file everything between a certain date to other date

Tags: linux, bash, logfile

I have a log file which looks like this:

```
01/09/18 07:04:37.020   ********

01/09/18 07:04:37.020   ********

01/09/18 07:04:37.020   ********

01/09/18 07:04:37.020   ********

01/09/18 07:04:37.020   ********

01/09/18 07:04:37.020   ********
```

I need to print all lines between for `01/08/18 22:53:28` till `01/08/18 23:12:19`, an important note is that these dates don't have to exist in my log file.

What I tried are the following things but they didn't work:

```
awk -F'[]]|[[]' \ '$0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "01/08/18 22:53:28" { p=1 }  $0 ~ /^\[/ && $2 >= "01/08/18 23:12:19" { p=0 } p { print $0 }' manager.log.6.gz
```

and command with sed

Answer (score 0):

if you have gawk available, you can make use of `mktime` function.  Your timestamp is not in `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format, so that you cannot directly compare (by `>= or <=`) them by string.

You can convert the given boundary to timestamp, and for each line, extract and convert the timestamp part, do the comparison to decide if the line should be printed or not.

Or you have to change your datetime string format into `YYYY-MM-DD HH...` to do the string comparison.

Read the gawk man page about `mktime` part, it is relative easy to use.

Comment: what do you mean by using the mktime function? You mean to convert the dates from the log to the dates that look like yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @Asa a date value has no "format", the "format" exists only in its string representation.  pls read the man page.

Comment: would this do 
awk '$0 >= "01/10/18 11:42:01" && $0 <= "01/10/18 12:02:59"' file.log